# when ransomware attack master's binlog, slave relaylog and data can be protected?

Tags: mysql, security, encryption, mariadb, replication

Recently, ransomware like Erebus is known to be capable of attacking linux server’s file.

If that is the case, suppose binlog file of my MasterDB is being encrypted,
can I count on my slave’s data being safely protected?

To answer the question myself, I’ve been reading the following article,
https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/01/09/how-does-mysql-replication-really-work/

Finally i've narrowed down to 3 following questions:

1. If master binlog file encrypted, would slave’s relaylog file be encrypted?
2. If relaylog file had been encrypted, would slave’s data become unavailable?
3. Then how can prevent this case? (if already use backup at once a week)

(If you cannot understand or Has any grammar problem, please notice.. sorry)

Comment: I am pretty much sure that if the binlog file gets encrypted in runtime, that would crash the MySQL service itself....

Comment: @Hackerman you mean relaylog cannot be changed because mysql system crashed, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, try running a lot of long test queries, and in the meantime use a encryption tool to try to encrypt the binlog(take a backup of the binlog just in case)

Comment: @Hackerman i will try that, then tell you about this result. thank you.

Comment: Glad to help @beCurious

Comment: The answers will be different for MySQL 5.7, 8.0, MariaDB 10.1, and 10.2.  Suggest you study 10.2 as being possibly the best _currently_ GA.